# How to include .ass subtitle file with html5 video tag

Tags: html, html5-video, subtitle

I'm using an .ass subtitle for changes in font size / font colors.

It works great with mpv, but I can't make it available in a web interface. (html5 tag)

I tried this but it doesn't work :

```
<video id="the_video" width="320" height="240" controls>
 <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 <track kind="subtitles" src="sub.ass" srclang="en" label="English" default>
</video>
```

Comment: afaik only webvtt is supported as standard subtitle type